# Omni Channel Routing Model - Least Active Explanation

Tags: omnichannel

I was going through the Salesforce help article (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=service_presence_routing_options.htm&language=en_US&type=0) to understand Omni Channel Routing Model - Least Active.

I have below questions regarding the example given in the page.

1. How come Agent A who is having 3 work items has the capacity impact of 1?
2. How come Agent B who has 1 active work item has the capacity impact of 4?
3. Finally, if someone please help me to understand the Least Active model that will be really helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How come Agent A who is having 3 work items has the capacity impact of 1?

You've misread this part. Agent A has a used capacity of 3; they have three items worth one capacity **each**. In this example, they're showing that A is less active than B.

> How come Agent B who has 1 active work item has the capacity impact of 4?

Each work item has a capacity value. In this case, B's work item has an assigned value of 4.

> Finally, if someone please help me to understand the Least Active model that will be really helpful.

In this text, A is less active than B, because A has 3 points of capacity used, while B has 4 points of capacity used. 3 is less than 4, so A is less active than B.

The difference between Least Active and Most Available is simply how the values are checked. In this case, A and B have the same capacity, so there's no difference. However, if A had the same items, and B had the same items, but A had a capacity of 5 and B had a capacity of 10, then the difference becomes apparent. Under Least Active, A would be selected, because 3 is less than 4, but under Most Available, B would be selected, because A has 2 available capacity (5-3=2), but B has 6 available capacity (10-4=6).

Answer (score 1):

To further understand how work capacity works, you have to understand how it is measured. this is defined in the [Omni-Channel for Administrators Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/service_presence_administrators.pdf).

You will see that there are Units of Capacity, which are consumed and based on the size of the work item that you specify in the routing configuration.
therefore, depending on the work item type, there are different "loads" based on the routing configuration you set as an admin.